# C++ - use std::unordered_set Key as hash output value

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, unordered-set

I want to store a set of MD5 hashes, using `std::unordered_set`. 
The struct I'm using, named MD5_HASH for instance, holds a raw buffer which represents an MD5 hash output. `std::unordered_set` basically uses a default hash function if one isn't provided. 
I don't need to perform any hash logic **on top of the buffer** I'm providing to `std::unordered_set`, due to the fact that its already the "product" of a hash function.

So, my question is basically - how can I use the key type of a `std::unordered_set` set as the output of the hash function, which it supposed to use?

Comment: I guess provide your own "hash" function in a lambda that just returns the parameter

Comment: You should probably use an identity function as the hash function.

Comment: You can define the unordered set as `unordered_set<string,your_defined_identity_function>  my_set;`.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` expects its hash function to produce a value of type `size_t` - typically, a 32-bit or a 64-bit unsigned integer. MD5 hash is 128 bit large. So you would necessarily need to provide some mapping between the two.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Hash

unordered_set and unordered_map require the hash function to be a model of this concept.

Note the return type.